# Integral of an analytic function

Tags: analysis

Is the integral of a real analytic function analytic? If it is so, how do you go about the proof? In particular, what guarantees that the Taylor series expansion of this integral converges to itself?

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of analyticity?

Comment: @Vim Yes. I am.

Comment: if so, you should have mentioned *power series* instead of Taylor series. Note the fact that power series converges uniformly within a radius smaller than its radius of convergence, then integrate term by term.

Comment: @Vim https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Real_analytic_function#Taylor_series  This page says that the power series expansion of an analytic function is the same as its Taylor series expansion.

Comment: usually I would take this as meaning their coefficients are identical. But in strict terminology, the Taylor series is a "pointwise" expression without any specification of "radius of convergence" (in fact in the notorious example $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ it has zero Taylor series about $0$, but has *no* power series expansion around $0$ at all), whereas the power series is defined on a non-degenerate *interval* with *strictly positive* radius of convergence. The intrinsic difference between them is huge.

Comment: @Vim Thanks. Got it!